# Animated Piechart fillmode?

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, quartz-core, cabasicanimation

im animating the stroke of a circle and it looks something like

[image: dribbble.com/shots/560534-Countdown/attachments/42066?project_id=57064]

i´m making a circle for a background, then i use the same path with thinner stroke to the animation path

```
CAShapeLayer *minutesBackground = [CAShapeLayer layer];
minutesBackground.path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake((screenWidth/2), (radiusMinutes+spacing)) radius:radiusMinutes startAngle:2*M_PI*0-M_PI_2 endAngle:2*M_PI*1-M_PI_2 clockwise:YES].CGPath;
minutesBackground.fillColor = clear;
minutesBackground.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
minutesBackground.lineWidth = minutesWidth+2;

minutesCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
minutesCircle.path=minutesBackground.path;
minutesCircle.fillColor=clear;
minutesCircle.strokeColor=[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
minutesCircle.lineWidth = minutesWidth;    
minutesCircle.shadowRadius = 2;
minutesCircle.shadowColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
minutesCircle.shadowOpacity = 5;
minutesCircle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

the animation is something i´ve found on the interwebs :)

```
minutesAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
minutesAnimation.duration = work;
minutesAnimation.repeatDuration=work;
minutesAnimation.removedOnCompletion=YES;
minutesAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
minutesAnimation.fromValue=@(0);
minutesAnimation.toValue=@(1);
minutesAnimation.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[minutesCircle addAnimation:minutesAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

if i set it to repeat for a duration, it has the desired effect, it draws, in the end it´s removed, and it draws again.

However, i have a button that pops up on animation completion, at the press of that button, i disable it and sets its alpha to 0.0 to hide it, and restart the timer.

when i restart the timer, the previously drawed circle is still there. (some thread issue maybe?)

any help appreciated, not sure if i shared enough code.. let me know if more would help my case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to have the `minutesCircle` disappear once the animation is done?

If so, the issue is that you've defined your `minutesCircle` with the default values for `strokeStart` (`0.0`) and `strokeEnd` (`1.0`). The `minutesAnimation` is animating the changing of `strokeEnd` from `0.0` to `1.0`. But, when the animation completes and is removed (because you've specified `removedOnCompletion` of `YES` and `fillMode` of `kCAFillModeRemoved`), the `strokeEnd` of the `minutesCircle` reverts back to it's original value, `1.0` (which means the orange arc will remain visible when animation is removed).

If you want it to make `minutesCircle` not visible once the animation is done, when you first create the `minutesCircle`, specify that both `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` are `0`:

```
minutesCircle.strokeStart = 0.0;
minutesCircle.strokeEnd = 0.0;
```

Now, when your animation completes and is removed, the `strokeEnd` of `minutesCircle` will revert to value it was originally, i.e. `0.0`, i.e. making the orange stroke no longer visible.

Comment: Setting those two values stopped the animation from happening at all